# Prove the generalization of the midpoint rule formula

Tags: definite-integrals, summation, numerical-methods, taylor-expansion

I saw in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_integration#Generalized_midpoint_rule_formula) the following formula:
$$\displaystyle\int_0^1 {f(x) \, dx} = \sum_{m=1}^M {\sum_{n=0}^\infty {\frac{\left({-1}\right)^n+1}{{\left(2M\right)^{n+1}}\left({n+1}\right)!} {{\left. f^{(n)}(x) \right.}_{\left|x=\frac{{m-\frac12}}{M}\right.}}}}$$

I wish to know how it was found, or how to prove it.
I guess they have just taken a Taylor series of the function, and set points with a pace of $\frac{1}{M}$?
Can anyone prove this equality?

Comment: Try using [Darboux’s](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux%27s_formula) formula as you almost have a Taylor Series. Should’nt there be a limit as M approaches infinity?

Comment: @TymaGaidash the formula actually requires that ϕ(t) be polynomial no?

Comment: Consider the case $M=1$, which then indeed reduces to the integration of the Taylor expansion for $f$ in the midpoint, and observe that the general case is a composite of that where the base case is applied to each of the intervals $[\frac{m-1}M,\frac{m}M]$ separately.

Comment: @LutzLehmann as mentioned, I thought about it, but I want to see a formal proof. Maybe in induction?

Comment: There is also the [Riemann Sum formula](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sum) which is almost like a midpoint rule.

Comment: @TymaGaidash sorry, I see no a close formula that allow to induct quickly the mentioned formula.

Comment: The answer does exactly what I said, the only concern is that the value does not change when the order of integration and series summation is exchanged. This should be largely covered by the requirement of the convergence of the Taylor expansion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$f(a+t)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty f^{(n)}(a) t^n \frac{1}{n!}$

$\int_{a-b}^{a+b} f(x)dx=\sum_{n=0}^\infty f^{(n)}(a) b^{n+1} \frac{1}{(n+1)!}-\sum_{n=0}^\infty f^{(n)}(a) (-b)^{n+1} \frac{1}{(n+1)!}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty f^{(n)}(a) (-1^n+1) b^{n+1} \frac{1}{(n+1)!}$

Taking $a=\frac{m-1/2}{M}$, $b=\frac{1}{2M}$:

$\int_{\frac{m-1}{M}}^{\frac{m}{M}} f(x)dx=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\left({-1}\right)^n+1}{{\left(2M\right)^{n+1}}\left({n+1}\right)!} {{\left. f^{(n)}(x) \right|}_{x=\frac{{m-1/2}}{M}}}$

$\int_{0}^{1} f(x)dx=\sum_{m=1}^M \int_{\frac{m-1}{M}}^{\frac{m}{M}} f(x)dx=\sum_{m=1}^M\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\left({-1}\right)^n+1}{{\left(2M\right)^{n+1}}\left({n+1}\right)!} {{\left. f^{(n)}(x) \right|}_{x=\frac{{m-1/2}}{M}}}$

Comment: can you explain the last row? how you get from the previous one to that?

Comment: hmm you've made summation ?

Comment: Yes, I've made summation of both parts from $m=1$ to $M$